# How to separate Favorites between participants in iCloud Shared Photo library?

Tags: photos, icloud

My wife and I share an iCloud Shared Photo Library, and I have recently discovered that we use likes / hearts / Favorites very differently. While albums and faces *do not sync* between separate participants, one person marking a photo or video as a Favorite effectively favorites it for all other participants. (I presume this is because they count as photo-level metadata.)

What set me on this path is that I'd like to photo shuffle my lock screen with *only my* favorites that excludes hers.

Here's what I've tried:

1. There appears to be no available Smart Album criteria to discern who contributed the photo to the shared library. (Even if it worked, this wouldn't solve my problem, since smart albums don't work on iOS/iPadOS.)
2. I can do a search for "Shared by Justin Searls" and "Favorites", but this doesn't actually filter *my favorites*, as it includes photos that she favorited. (Even if it worked, this wouldn't solve my problem, since lock screen Photo Shuffle can only be set up on an album or one of the automated categories—you can perform a search from the UI but only to manually select and add photos at a single point.)
3. Searching the Photos actions in Shortcuts to see if this exposes anything useful

Thus exhausts my ideas. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is with 2 separate iCloud accounts?

Comment: Yes, this is 2 accounts and one [iCloud Shared Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213248)